# Photoshop cs6 ubuntu layerchanges won't update

Tags: wine, 17.04, playonlinux, photoshop

I've just got Photoshop Cs6 working on Ubuntu making use of Playonlinux. Took me some time since I just transferred from Windows to Ubuntu (which I'm until now very happy about). Now every time when I perform an action like hide a layer, making use of color overlay the action doesn't execute within the design.

Now by accident I found out that when I minimize or maximize the screen, the action gets executed. Since it very unpractical to minimize or maximize after each action it would be great to fix this issue.

I've tried to restart PlayOnLinux but it doesn't make a difference. I'm making use of Ubuntu 17.04

Anybody can help me with a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think that Photoshop uses GPU acceleration (OpenGL) and it seems like there is some problem with updating GPU buffers. I would recommend to update Wine or GPU drivers.

If it does not help, try to disable GPU acceleration: Edit - Preferences - Performance - Use Graphics Processor.

BTW. I use [Photopea editor](https://www.Photopea.com) on Linux, it can do all I need and save my work back into a PSD file.

**Mod Message**: Whilst on-topic, the author does not disclose their affiliation with his blog site: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/609/photoshop-animated-png/99851#99851

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ivan. Updating Wine does not seem to work as I'm still getting same results. Any other idea's about what I could try?